# Java concurrency issue about visibility

Tags: java, multithreading

I read that the `synchronized` method or block provides two features: "mutual exclusion"  and "visibility". I want to know two things.

```
public class A{

  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private C obj = new C();

  public void methodA(){

      synchronized(lock){
        obj.x = 1;
        obj.y=3;
       }
    }

public void methodB(C obj2){

          synchronized(lock){
           obj2.x = obj.x;
           }


}

}
```

Let's assume that we have 2 threads that called `methodA` on a global shared object of type `A` ,  and the `lock` is acquired by `thread1` , now after `thread1` release the `lock` . now the visibility is that all other thread will read the changes to `obj`? I.e. will every change inside the `synchronized` block be visible? Or should I change C object to `volatile` to make it change visible to others?

Comment: i am not an expert so be patient with me

Comment: i want to make sure that i understand every thing correctly

Comment: If you want to learn exactly how concurrency works in Java, then the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is the best book you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is every thing change inside the synchronized block will be visibile?

Yes that's the idea. The [JLS 17.45](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) defines happens before relationships. In particular:

> *An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.*

So when thread2 acquires the lock, you have the guarantee that it will see the changes made by thread1 while holding that same lock.

> Should I change C object to volatile to make it change visible to others?

volatile guarantees that if you write: `obj = new C();` somewhere, a subsequent read of `obj` will see that it now refers to a new object. However, it does not provide any such guarantee with regards to the "content" of obj. So if you write: `obj.x = someValue;`, with obj being volatile, you don't have a guarantee that the change will be visible to another thread. Unless you make `x` volatile too.

Comment: so there is no need to make C object volatile ?

Comment: @user4o01 Not only there is no need, but if you only made it volatile, it would not provide the same guarantees.

Comment: no maybe you misunderstand the question ,its my fault . i mean keeping the same code above and also add the volatile to the C object .so it will be visible

Comment: thanks you very much .  i wish i can give you million up vote because you clarify  things in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Making `obj` `volatile` will make the *reference* to the C object `volatile`. i.e. visible outside the synchronised block. It won't affect the members of that object.

i.e. a reassignment to obj will be visible to another thread. A reassignment to its members won't.

Answer (score 1):

> now the visibility is that all other thread will read the changes to obj ?

Only threads inside a synchronized block for that lock.

> is every thing change inside the synchronized block will be visibile ?

Only probably. For guarenteed visibility the thread has to be inside a synchronized block.

> or i should change C object to volatile ?

It will not help if you didn't have synchronized and will not make any difference here. `volatile` will only changes the behaviour of the `obj` reference, not it's fields.

Answer (score 0):

No, accessing to `obj` fields is still not thread-safe. Synchronization on the lock object only allows you thread-safe operations for writing values to `obj`'s fields in this block.

**UPD**: `volatile` for `obj` will not help you, because you don't change this field's own reference value.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, another method can simply give you access to the variable obj, without the lock too. What you have to ensure is that all accesses to obj must be guarded carefully through locks, so that obj is not in an inconsistent state (as defined by a programmer).

In your particular example, it looks consistent enough to me.